# Sending mail on a TRIGGER stops insert from taking place (and email doesnt send)

Tags: sql-server, email, triggers

I have a simple trigger on INSERT

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendErrorEmail]
   ON  [dbo].[tblNewErrorLog]
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   


    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name='myprofile',
        @recipients='me@me.com',
        @subject='error in the database',
        @body = 'check it out'

END
```

- If I manually add a row using Management Studio, everything is fine, row added email sent.
- If an error is logged via the service, nothing. No email, no new row.
- If I remove the trigger - things work as expected, row added.
- If I keep the trigger, but remove the email SP, its ok. New row added.

So, the error is obviously something to do with the email, maybe security? I have tried logging in the the credentials used by the service to connect to the DB, and It works if I add a row manually.

I am also a bit worried that even if the email doesn't sent, the insert fails, why is that?

Thoughts on where to start troubleshooting this are most welcome.

Thanks!

Edits:
Removed try catch from code
general Tidy up

Comment: You should not couple the failure of sending the email to the trigger. Instead, either add a flag column to the table in question, and run a separate process that sends out emails for unflagged rows, or use a queue table. There's a ton of things that can go wrong when sending email, you **do not** want to tie the success rate of logging the error to those problems.

Comment: Whatever error is occurring is getting eaten by BEGIN CATCH, END CATCH, remove that or add additional error logging in the exception handling

Comment: sorry, the try catch was my copy pasting my attempts to troubleshoot, same things happen if I remove the try catch totally. I wanted to see if the row would still get inserted if the catch was hit

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: `sp_send_dbmail` already decouples the trigger from any SMTP activity. It uses internal SQL Server queues (Service Broker) and the SMTP activity is handled by an external process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger is executing in a context that does not have EXECUTE permission to the `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` procedure. Most likely you are falling into the constrained `EXECUTE AS` sandboxing, see [Understanding Execution Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187096%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This would manifest exactly as you describe the problem: it works from SSMS but not in your application.

See [Call a procedure in another database from an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/) for an example how to use code signing to grant execute permission to code running in EXECUTE AS context sandbox.

If the code is not running under EXECUTE As then is just a simple matter of permissions. You can either grant [msdb] access and EXECUTE permission on `sp_send_dbmail` to the service account that you application uses, or you can again use code signing as above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added exec permissions onto the sp_send_dbmail for the user in question and it was fine. I don't like the fact that the insert failed however. I guess its by design that if a trigger linked to an action fails, everything fails?

Comment: Triggers by default are executed with [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).